# Why are all fields null when querying with schema?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using structured streaming with schema specified with the help of case class and encoders to get the streaming dataframe.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
case class SampleLogEntry(
  dateTime: Timestamp,
  clientIp: String,
  userId: String,
  operation: String,
  bucketName: String,
  contAccUsrId: String,
  reqHeader: Integer,
  reqBody: Integer,
  respHeader: Integer,
  respBody: Integer,
  totalReqResSize: Integer,
  duration: Integer,
  objectName: String,
  httpStatus: Integer,
  s3ReqId: String,
  etag: String,
  errCode: Integer,
  srcBucket: String
)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val sampleLogSchema = Encoders.product[SampleLogEntry].schema

val rawData = spark
  .readStream
  .format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("header", true)
  .schema(sampleLogSchema)
  .load("/Users/home/learning-spark/logs")
```

However, I am getting only `null` values with this schema:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+--------+----+------+-----+----------+------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+---------+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------+-------+---------+
|dateTime|  IP|userId|s3Api|bucketName|accessUserId|reqHeader|reqBody|respHeader|respBody|totalSize|duration|objectName|httpStatus|reqestId|objectTag|errCode|srcBucket|
+--------+----+------+-----+----------+------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+---------+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------+-------+---------+
|    null|null|  null| null|      null|        null|     null|   null|      null|    null|     null|    null|      null|      null|    null|     null|   null|     null|
|    null|null|  null| null|      null|        null|     null|   null|      null|    null|     null|    null|      null|      null|    null|     null|   null|     null|
|    null|null|  null| null|      null|        null|     null|   null|      null|    null|     null|    null|      null|      null|    null|     null|   null|     null|
|    null|null|  null| null|      null|        null|     null|   null|      null|    null|     null|    null|      null|      null|    null|     null|   null|     null|
```

When I changed every field in this schema to String it worked fine and it gets me the following expected output. Why?

```
+--------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+---------+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+---------+-----------------+---------+
|            dateTime|       IP|userId|  s3Api|bucketName|accessUserId|reqHeader|reqBody|respHeader|respBody|totalSize|duration|objectName|httpStatus|            reqestId|objectTag|          errCode|srcBucket|
+--------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+---------+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+---------+-----------------+---------+
|2019-07-18 00:00:...|10.29.2.5|  null|unknown|      null|        null|        0|      0|         0|     250|      250|     247|      null|       400|08084d90-299e-14a...|        0|InvalidBucketName|     null|
|2019-07-18 00:00:...|10.29.2.6|  null|unknown|      null|        null|        0|      0|         0|     250|      250|     291|      null|       400|08084d92-299e-14a...|        0|InvalidBucketName|     null|
|2019-07-18 00:00:...|10.29.2.5|  null|unknown|      null|        null|        0|      0|         0|     250|      250|     246|      null|       400|08084d94-299e-14a...|        0|InvalidBucketName|     null|
|2019-07-18 00:00:...|10.29.2.6|  null|unknown|      null|        null|        0|      0|         0|     250|      250|     227|      null|       400|08084d96-299e-14a...|        0|InvalidBucketName|     null|
|2019-07-18 00:00:...|10.29.2.5|  null|unknown|      null|        null|        0|      0|         0|     250|      250|     287|      null|       400|08084d98-299e-14a...|        0|InvalidBucketName|     null|
```

Sample of my data -

```
2019-07-22 00:10:15,030|10.29.2.6||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|251||400|05591428-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|
2019-07-22 00:10:15,334|10.1.198.41|splunk|putObject|splunk|splunk|216|75|96|0|387|14117|aws%2Fdma%2F10%2F1b%2F32%7E6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_splunk_app_aws_Detailed_Billing%2FguidSplunk-6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2Fmetadata_checksum|200|0559142a-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|73d2834dffe4f89007d892f20326e0e6|0|
2019-07-22 00:10:15,400|10.1.198.41|splunk|putObject|splunk|splunk|217|689|96|0|1002|27898|aws%2Fdma%2F10%2F1b%2F32%7E6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_splunk_app_aws_S3_Access_Log%2Freceipt.json|200|0559142c-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|3214c88c08b9d96b085a8ca5921827e6|0|
2019-07-22 00:10:15,511|10.1.198.41|splunk|putObject|splunk|splunk|217|697|96|0|1010|5483|aws%2Fdma%2F10%2F1b%2F32%7E6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_splunk_app_aws_CloudFront_Access_Log%2Freceipt.json|200|0559142e-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|659d8a9f6b899755e03b709c069016cd|0|
2019-07-22 00:10:16,911|10.1.198.41|splunk|putObject|splunk|splunk|216|75|96|0|387|7295|aws%2Fdma%2F10%2F1b%2F32%7E6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_wildfire_report%2FguidSplunk-6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2Fmetadata_checksum|200|05591430-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|bf6873f745bc661bc940b7f13a00c314|0|
2019-07-22 00:10:16,952|10.1.198.41|splunk|putObject|splunk|splunk|217|696|96|0|1009|5206|aws%2Fdma%2F10%2F1b%2F32%7E6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_traps%2Freceipt.json|200|05591432-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|e06d1193d3ed2503d6e378630cf6003b|0|
2019-07-22 00:10:17,263|10.1.198.41|splunk|putObject|splunk|splunk|217|699|96|0|1012|5142|aws%2Fdma%2F10%2F1b%2F32%7E6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_aperture%2Freceipt.json|200|05591434-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|97acdf7a24b733c011aa7fad0637b526|0|
2019-07-22 00:10:17,540|10.1.198.41|splunk|putObject|splunk|splunk|219|20787|96|0|21102|6861|aws%2Fdma%2F10%2F1b%2F32%7E6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_firewall%2FguidSplunk-6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2Fmetadata.csv|200|05591436-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|2bc8b90fdb1b5b156cf864005ca6c060|0|
2019-07-22 00:10:17,591|10.1.198.41|splunk|putObject|splunk|splunk|217|783|96|0|1096|5074|aws%2Fra%2F10%2F1b%2F32%7E6A3CD05A-AA46-47CF-B2E0-AA16F08FB944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_splunk_app_aws_nobody_NSbbffede24e849f9b%2Freceipt.json|200|05591438-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|28da300a36bb1e054db7f60a8aad5b4a|0|
2019-07-22 00:10:17,826|10.29.2.5||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|196||400|0559143a-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|
2019-07-22 00:10:20,030|10.29.2.6||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|272||400|0559143c-86b7-14a8-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|
```

How do I set up schema so that I can read data from log files with specified datatypes of the fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `dateTime: Timestamp` field. With a schema you're telling Spark SQL to use a timestamp-aware parser that does the string-to-timestamp conversion and fails due to an incorrect format. Without a schema, all data are strings so anything matches fine.

You have to specify a proper format using `timestampFormat` option to parse `2019-07-22 00:10:15,030`-like dates. They simply don't match what the underlying timestamp parser expect and hence all the values get `null`s.

Use `option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS")` with `format("csv")` and the structured/streaming query should be fine.

p.s. It's a more general issue in Spark SQL (and showed itself in Spark Structured Streaming that uses the Spark SQL engine under the covers for execution).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jacek Laskowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305344/jacek-laskowski) for this answer. I changed my `datetime` field to `java.sql.Timestamp` and included option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS") in my streaming read operation. The overall code looks like this -

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
case class SampleLogEntry(
  dateTime: Timestamp,
  clientIp: String,
  userId: String,
  operation: String,
  bucketName: String,
  contAccUsrId: String,
  reqHeader: Integer,
  reqBody: Integer,
  respHeader: Integer,
  respBody: Integer,
  totalReqResSize: Integer,
  duration: Integer,
  objectName: String,
  httpStatus: Integer,
  s3ReqId: String,
  etag: String,
  errCode: Integer,
  srcBucket: String
)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val sampleLogSchema = Encoders.product[SampleLogEntry].schema

val rawData = spark
  .readStream
  .format("csv")
  .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("header", true)
  .schema(sampleLogSchema)
  .load("/Users/home/learning-spark/logs")
```

Answer (score -2):

It's just working fine for me.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

scala> case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
defined class Person

scala> val data = List(("id|name"),("10|xyz")).toDS()
data: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> val delimited = spark.read.
     |       option("delimiter", "|").
     |       option("header", "true").
     |       schema(Encoders.product[Person].schema).
     |       csv(data)
delimited: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string]

scala> delimited.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)


scala> delimited.show(false)
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|10 |xyz |
+---+----+
```

> val rawData = spark
>         .readStream
>         .format("")
>         .option("delimiter", "|")
>         .option("header", "true")
>         .schema(sampleLogSchema) 
>         .load("/Users/home/learning-spark/logs")

in you code can you change the format option to **csv**

Comment: I tried changing the format to `csv` but still is the same. What is the spark version you are using?

Comment: Downvoted. Please use `java.sql.Timestamp` in your sample data. It's not supposed to work with the change.